# How to get proper multi select above background layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the Fancy Product Designer, which is using fabricjs and canvas elements.

I've created this scenario:
https://www.screenart.media/branchen/baeckerei-konditorei/plakat-liebe-verschenken/

There you can see multiple layers like background (Hintergrund), coffee mug (Kaffeetasse), muffin box.

I would like to enable multi select on the canvas object.

Problem is, that this would always select the background layer, too.

Is it possible to avoid selecting an object (like the background) when I want to only select the mug and muffinbox by click-and-dragging a selection box?

Perhaps it's possible to split the click-drag event into two steps?
1. Click-drag on an unselected object would just open the selection box (pass the event to the canvas background).
2. Click an object to select it, then click-drag would move the selected object.

This would make the behavior more consistent (also think of selecting a bunch of objects and moving them all together), no?

What do you think? Any idea on how to implement this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the background image is not actually a backgroundImage in the fabric canvas meaning of it?

Comment: It's  how the FPD works. It gives the user the ability to modify objects but not the background image itself. Thus I had to add the background image as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the selectable property of your object to false?
It's as simple as:

```
object.set({selectable: false});
```

Comment: If I set the layer "Hintergrund" to "selectable: false", I cannot draw a selection box. Only when I completely disable all interactions to it by clicking the lock icon in the layers panel, I can draw a box.
But this is not what we need. What we need is a much more general way of selecting objects on the canvas. The first click drag should always open a selection box. Only a click should select an object.